# Solubility of pyridine and pyrrole in water

Tags: solubility, aromatic-compounds

Pyridine and pyrrole are two of the first aromatic heterocycles encountered in organic chemistry. Recently, I was surprised to find that their solubility properties are vastly different.

The website of [American Chemical Society](https://www.acs.org/content/acs/en/molecule-of-the-week/archive/p/pyridine.html#:%7E:text=Pyridine%20is%20completely%20miscible%20with,pyridine%20is%20a%20weak%20base.) says

> Pyridine is completely miscible with water...

While ChemicalBook says

> [Pyridine](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB8852825.htm) is hygroscopic and is miscible with H2O and organic solvents.

> [Pyrrole](https://www.chemicalbook.com/ChemicalProductProperty_EN_CB3852794.htm#:%7E:text=Pyrrole%20has%20only%20limited%20solubility,coloration%20due%20to%20air%20oxidation.) has only limited solubility in water but is miscible with many organic solvents.

The two molecules appear to be similar in size, and both have nitrogen. My first guess is that their dipole moments are different, since the lone pair in pyridine does not participate in aromatic resonance, but I can't seem to find relevant data on this. Also, it feels strange that a molecule like pyridine is miscible in water.

Comment: Sure both have a nitrogen and both are aromatic. But their structures are vastly different. For example, the lone pair of pyridine is readily available for H-bonding with water while that of pyrrole is blended into aromatic system so not available. Only a polar bond of $\ce{N-H}$ make it slightly soluble in water.

Comment: Difference in basicity is probably most important here.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne While the lone pair on pyridine can participate in hydrogen bonding, can't the hydrogen on pyrrole also, with the oxygen in H2O? Or maybe there's a significant difference in their strength which I overlooked?